# Independent statements about generated $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

I base my question on [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258842/a-question-about-sigma-algebras-and-rectangles). I saw it at Math Overflow and as nobody answer it, although its bounty, I decided to post it here.

Consider the statements $P$ and $Q$:

> $P$: Every subset of the plane belongs to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by arbitrary rectangle.

That is, $C\subseteq \Bbb{R}^2 \implies C\in \sigma(\{A\times B : A\subseteq \Bbb{R} \mbox{ and } B\subseteq \Bbb{R}\})$. And

> $Q$: Every continuum-sized family of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ is contained in a countably generated $\sigma$-algebra.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455797/unprovability-results-in-zfc/455929#455929) is proved that statement $P$ is independent from $ZFC$; and [here](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/res/bor.pdf)  is (partially) proved that $Q$ is also independent from $ZFC$.

Question 1: Why does $P\implies Q$ ? As the author of the [initial question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258842/a-question-about-sigma-algebras-and-rectangles) said.

Question 2: Does $Q\implies P$ ?

I think Question 1 must be much simpler, but I'm just curious about this and I'm far from being a specialist at the matter. I'm sorry for the lack of development of a try :(

Thank you for any help

Comment: The argument for $P \implies Q$ is essentially in the first paragraph of [this anwer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2081991/4280), I think. There it is done for $\aleph_1$ instead of $\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: About 3 yrs ago I   asked about P here and cross-posted it to MathOverflow, where I got the A that it was undecidable in ZFC, which surprised me because it once appeared as a Problem in American Mathematical Monthly, circa 1972. (with an asterisk, meaning neither the proposer nor the editors had a solution).

Comment: @DanielWainfleet , interesting! Do you know how to find some pdf of this event (which appears the problem $P$)? I searched for it quickly and found nothing...

Comment: If by "This event" you mean the appearance of the problem in Amer. Math.  Monthly, all I can suggest is a  search of their archives. I no longer have the paper copy.

Answer (score 2):

First part  of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455797/unprovability-results-in-zfc/455929#455929) must help you on $P\implies Q$