# Proving that the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets on the real line is not separable (i.e. countably generated).

Tags: measure-theory

It is known that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal B}(\mathbb{R}) $ is countably generated. And it is also known that ${\cal B}(\mathbb{R}) \subsetneq {\cal L}(\mu^*, \mathbb{R}), $ the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets. In fact, the latter is the completion of the former. Is there a simple way to prove that  ${\cal L}(\mu*, \mathbb{R}) $ is not countably generated?

In the beginning I thought that since $  {\cal L}(\mu^*, \mathbb{R}) $ contains  ${\cal B}(\mathbb{R}) $ and the closure, a countable collection cannot generate it, unless the closure itself is countable, which one should prove it exists. I also wondered if the fact that  $  {\cal L}(\mu^*, \mathbb{R}) $ contains all singletons as its only atoms, could be exploited, but I ended up with some headache instead. Does anyone have a good suggestion?

Thank you.

Maurice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to prove that any countably generated $\sigma$-algebra has cardinality at most that of the continuum. That takes some time to show, but it is done in the top answer to this question [Is the intersection of two countably generated $\sigma$-algebras countably generated?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283035/is-the-intersection-of-two-countably-generated-sigma-algebras-countably-gener/283486#283486). Then recall that any subset of the Cantor set is Lebesgue measurable so there are clearly more than $\aleph_1$ of them.

Btw, you shouldn’t equate countable generability and separability: the Lebesgue sets are separable in the metric induced by the measure.

Comment: Thank you. I was just thinking about the $\sigma$-algebra being or not being countably generated which some authors call separable and not the sets themselves.